# Syntax Error React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have completed the React/Elixir "learnphoenix.io" tutorial and I am on the Routes and Views part. I have a compilation error

```
ERROR in ./app/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:22)

  4 | import { default as Home } from   "./components/Home"
  5 | import { default as Settings } from   "./components/Settings"
> 6 | const App =   props   => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
    |                         ^
  7 | ReactDOM.render(
  8 |       <Router history={hashHistory}>
  9 |               <Route path="/" component={App}>

 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

I'm new to React so I don't understand very well.

EDIT1:
There is the webpack.config.js :

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'babel']
        },
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
  }
}
```

app/index.js :

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory }   from "react-router"
import { default as Home } from "./components/Home"
import { default as Settings } from "./components/Settings"
const   App =   props   => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
ReactDom.render(
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="settings"  component={Settings}/>
                </Route>
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById("root")
)
```

app/Home/index.js :

```
import React from "react"

export class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>Home component</div>)
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in ReactJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963686/syntax-error-in-reactjs) - in short, you need to use a tool (most commonly Babel with the appropriate React/JSX modules enabled) to transpile JSX to JS.

Comment: did you included babel presets - ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']

Comment: @TomFenech I did all there are in the topic but it don't work... It show me `Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "babel" relative to directory "/home/jeremy/Bureau/projets/phoenix-chat-frontend/app"
`

Comment: There is not babel preset. Add this:  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct jsx ES6 syntax but it looks like it is saved as .js.

You need to have a transpile step in the build proces, probably with Babel

Comment: I have installed `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev` but it don't work ...

Comment: Correct syntax indeed.

Comment: @mjerem34 you are not setting the presets in the babel configuration. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963686/syntax-error-in-reactjs

Comment: He has test: /\.js$/, so this is not a extension problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your presets:

['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']

This is not wrong

```
const App =   props   => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
```

And it should transpile to:

```
"use strict";

var App = function App(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        props.children
    );
};
```

But you are missing `react` transpiler part. I duped the error [in Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Cstage-1&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%20%20%20%20const%20App%20%3D%20props%20%3D%3E%20(%3Cdiv%3E%7Bprops.children%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E)) in case I haven't used react tag.

Evaluate Presets: es2015, es2016, stage-1   Line Wrap  Minify (Babili) Babel 6.22.1

```
repl: Unexpected token (1:26)
> 1 |     const App = props => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
    |                           ^
```

This is called the fat arrow syntax, the props is a parameter to the stateless function. You are setting te name App for the function and you are returning the JSX.

When you don't have react, JSX part cannot be transpiled and from there the error.

Comment: I have added `['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']` and I have no error but it don't show the page in firefox ... see initial post edit to see my Home/index.js content

Comment: Ask another question bro. This quest was about the error (@mjerem34).

Comment: @mjerem34, Please try to ✓the answer helped you best.

Comment: Ok, I will try ... Thanks you